# how to replace string with result of function in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to insert filename and line number into some places in the file. For example this line:

```
_debug('init');
```

I want to replace

```
:s/debug('/debug('(%current_filename_here%:%current_line_number_here%)\ /g
```

to get this

```
_debug('(filename.ext:88) init');
```

I try to use expand(`'%:t'`) to get filename and line(`"."`) to get line number, but I don't know how to use it in replace expression.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`\=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3as%5C=). For example:

```
:s@_debug('\zs@\=printf('(%s:%d) ', expand('%:t'), line('.'))@
```

---

> When the {replacement} starts with `"\="` it is evaluated as an expression,

Comment: I can not use Vim functions directly in expression, through printf only, right?

Comment: You can use vim functions. @ is just a separator. It is customary to write the function as `:s///`, but `:s###` works as well, as does `:s@@@`...

Comment: @Neka `printf` is a function in vim. You can use `\='('.expand('%:t').':'.line('.').') '`, as you can see, I use `.` to concatenate multiple expression.